# String pointers in c language

Tags: c, string, pointers

Can any one tell me why the following program crashes.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    char **str;
    strcpy(*str, "One");
    puts(*str);
}
```

And why the following program doesn't.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    char **str;
    *str = "One";
    puts(*str);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`strcopy` assumes you have memory available.

In the second one you are pointing `*str` at the statically allocated "One" `char[]` literal which decays to a pointer. This is actually undefined as well, since `str` isn't init'd you're still copying a pointer to gibberish.

In the first one you're trying to copy a string to wherever `*str` points to when left uninitialized. This will almost certainly crash your program since it's just pointing to some garbage address.

So to do this correctly

```
//allocate space for ARRAY_SIZE pointers
char **str = malloc(sizeof(char*) * ARRAY_SIZE); 
*str = "One"; // assign the address of "One"
puts(*str); // print it.
...
free(str);
```

Comment: @DrewMcGowen the "One" literal one? There's no modification there, if he had tried to do `char* foo = "meh"; foo[2] = 'r'` than I'd expect it to crash

Comment: Bah, that's what I get for trying to reply on a Monday morning :P

Comment: I think the second one works just due to luck. He sets up a pointer-to-pointer to `char`, and never allocates memory for it. Dereferencing it with `*str = "One";` and trying to store the address of `"One"` into unallocated memory leads to undefined behavior, undefined behavior leads to suffering, and suffering leads to the Dark Side.

Answer (score 2):

The first one:

str decleared as char**, **But** you did not use memorey allocation for that!

Remmber, str is pointer to pointer, so if you want to keep an adress in str*, you should use memorey allocation **or** initialize in the declaration row!!

In your code, str* is just an adress, not a string!

The second one is about the same idea.

Answer (score 2):

Your second one doesn't crash due to sheer luck. It ought to be like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    char **str = malloc(sizeof *str);
    if ( str != NULL ) {
        *str = "One";
        puts(*str);
        free(str);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

or:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    char * str;
    str = "One";
    puts(str);

    return 0;
}
```

As you wrote it, you're trying to stuff the address of the string literal `"One"` into unallocated memory, which gives you undefined behavior.

Your first one crashes for the same reason, you're trying to copy the bytes `'O'`, `'n'`, `'e'`, and `'\0'` into unallocated memory.

Comment: The second not crashing isn't sheer _good_ luck, it's sheer _bad_ luck.

Answer (score 0):

In the first program, you are doing a string copy to a non memory allocated pointer.  (*str) has no malloc, new, etc..

In the second one, you are pointing the string pointer to a stack variable.  the str pointer will only be valid during the context of the call and when the function exits the str pointer will point to an invalid space.  Since this is main(), you don't see that

Comment: The second one is also wrong. The questioner is dereferencing `str`, which is uninitialized. The not crashing is simply coincidence.